# Sympy rewrite expression to template

Tags: sympy

If I have an expression such as `c1 / (c2*s + c3)` I would like sympy to transform the expression to a template looking like `C1 / (s + C2)` such that `C1 = c1/c2` and `C2 = c3/c2`.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Normally one would use `Wild` and `match` to do this, but they don't seem to be powerful enough to recognize that one expression is really in the form of the other.

Comment: Yes, the result has to have exactly the same form as the "wildcard"-structure. It could be a nice feature to include.

Answer (score 0):

So you are asking "What must C1 and C2 be to make this true?" `solve` can answer that question:

```
>>> v = var('c1:4 C1:3 s')
>>> expr = c1 / (c2*s + c3)
>>> tmpl = C1 / (s + C2)
>>> t = tmpl.free_symbols - expr.free_symbols
>>> solve(expr - tmpl, t, dict=True)
[{C1: c1/c2, C2: c3/c2}]
```